# Youtube video won't fill frame in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, video, youtube, embed

So I have this Youtube video that I'm trying to embed on one of my pages: http://www.rodypolis.com/videotest.html

The above link is to a test page containing the video. When played on any other browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) the video fills the frame as it should, and there are no problems.

However, I tried this with Internet Explorer 11, and the video won't fill the frame. Instead, the video shows up really small inside of the frame. I've tried a few things to fix it, but I can't.

Do you have any ideas on why IE11 won't allow the video to fill the whole frame? How can I force it to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin called [fitvids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) that will do what you need it to do. Otherwise just style your video object with css, giving it a width and a height. There's also a youtube autoresizer available [here](https://skipser.googlecode.com/files/youtube-autoresizer.js) (takes a minute to come up)

```
div#videocontainer{    
   max-width:80%;
   height: 400px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-top:50px;
   margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: "Otherwise just style your video object with css" I haven't been able to make this work. Could you give me an example of how you would write it? Simply using CSS would be my preferred method, but no matter what I type it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rodolphe i think you should include the autoreziaer

Comment: @Rodolphe first of all you are using px in your container  - always a bad idea - you should use percentages e.g width:100%; height:auto;

Comment: @Rodolphe use a css stylesheet aswell instead of inline style - it's much easier to control your css when it's altogether in one file

Comment: OK, added the autoresizer. Still nothing on IE11. Also changed the embed width/height to 100%

Comment: @Rodolphe in your div#videocontainer you have width:700px height:298px change these to 100% and auto

Comment: Based on what I see, it seems that internet Explorer 11 doesn't agree that my video is 1920x817, so it's forcing it to be 1920x1080. So because of that the video is boxed in. The question now is why, and how can I stop it.

Comment: suggest max-width:100%; height:500; (height of div)

Comment: So by doing that the video fills the whole frame. However, I can't increase the size of the container on the actual page, so it's going to have to work at 700x298, or it's not going to work at all. The thing that makes me angry is that ALL other browsers I've tried work fine, but of course, stupid IE is here to mess things up! Man, I hate that browser!